# What is the difference between the Matlab "smooth" function, and the Python "scipy.signal.savgol_filter"?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, signals

I am currently translating some code written in Matlab, and re-writing it in Python. I have a function below in Matlab:

```matlab
yy = smooth(y, span, 'sgolay', degree)
```

This function is meant to smooth the signal `y`, using the Savitzky-Golay calculation. I found a Python function that applies this calculation to an input signal.

```py
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
yy = savgol_filter(y, span, degree)
```

Would both of these functions produce the same output `yy` for the same input `y`? If not, is there any Python equivalent of the Matlab `smooth` function?

Thank you in advance for the answers.

Comment: You can literally `edit smooth` in MATLAB and see exactly what mathematics is being performed. Obligatory comment that you should be wary of MATLAB's license agreement before creating any direct derivatives. MATLAB's [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sgolay.html) also explicitly references the academic papers for the sgolay filter definition (at the bottom)

Comment: The only difference would be in how they handle the edges.  Most of the online Matlab documentation for their functions has a button "Try This Example" that opens up an online Matlab session.  I used a Matlab online session to see the output of `smooth` for several input arrays and several different values for `span` and `degree`, and compared it to the output of `savgol_filter` in Python.  They appeared to be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compare the impulse response function of both to answer your question. From the below test, I would say it is not a bad idea to think they does the same thing. As mentioned in the comments, boundary cases like samples without neighbors, odd/even samples, etc could be implemented differently.

```matlab
span=5;
degree=2;
y=zeros(100,1);
y(length(y)/2)=1;
figure,stem(y),hold on, stem(smooth(y, span, 'sgolay', degree))
legend({'input','PSF'})
```

[image]

```py
#%%
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

span=5
degree=2
y=np.zeros(100);
y[y.shape[0]//2]=1
yy = savgol_filter(y, span, degree)


plt.stem(y,linefmt='red',label='input')
plt.stem(yy,linefmt='blue',label='PSF')
plt.show()
```

[image]